# Echo with single and double quote in PHP

Tags: php, echo, quotes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between single quote and double quote string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php)

Hi,

What is the difference between `echo 'Test Data';` and `echo "Test Data";` in PHP.

Both statements give me same output.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 14):

I believe that double quotes allow variables to be replaced by the value :

```
echo "test = $test";
```

displays :

> test = 2

```
echo 'test = $test';
```

displays :

> test = $test

Answer (score 1):

Single-quoted strings will not have variables or escape sequences expanded by the interpreter, whereas double-quoted strings will - look at the different output of:

```
$foo = 'bar';
echo 'This is a $foo';
echo "This is a $foo";
```

Single-quoted strings are hence marginally 'better' to use as the interpreter won't have to check the contents of the string for a variable reference.

Comment: Double or single quotes make absolutely no difference for speed at all.  
See my personal test @ http://gnur.nl/speed.php

Comment: @gnur: After having a quick look at a few benchmarks, you're probably right that the performance difference is negligible. The deciding factor should be readability and ease of code (which I think tends to side with `"This is a $foo."` over `'This is a ' . $foo . '.'`.)

Comment: I agree for readability, but when you use more languages it makes more sense to not include variables in your strings because they aren't supported most of the them.